# Finding the expected value of recursive algorithm/pseudocode?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, logic, probability-distributions

Need a bit of help understanding how to evaluate the expected value of a recursive algorithm, particularly in the form of code. My pick(p) method is basically a simple Bernoulli distribution, and n will always be a power of 2 (1 and above).

```
recursion(p, n)
  if (n == 1) return pick(p)
  else return 2*recursion(p,n/2)
```

Just tracing through the code, I appear to get roughly np as my expected value, but I'm not sure how to exactly formalize that and whether that's how you would even calculate the expected value in this case. As a bonus, how would one look at the variance?

Thanks.

Comment: If $n$ is always a power of $2$ you can prove by induction on $n$ that the return value is exactly $n\times\operatorname{pick}(p)$.

Comment: That sounds good to me, thank you. Do you have any idea of how we can go about figuring out the variance? I see that it will likely be through induction... But not sure of the nuts and bolts of it.

Answer (score 0):

The only "random" part is what happens in the base case of the recursion.

So the value is:

2 * 2 * .. $log_2(n)$ times * pick(p) = n * pick(p)

The expected value of pick(p) by definition is p, so the expected value of the recursion is np.

For variance, it's easy because you know that the recursion can only take two values, n (where pick(p) = 1) and 0 (where pick(p) = 0)

So Var(recursion) = E(recursion^2) - E(recursion)^2

= $(n^2 * p + 0*(1-p)) - (np)^2$

= $n^2p - n^2p^2 = n^2p(1-p)$